# Milliseconds or milliseconds?

Tags: capitalization

Which is the correct capitalization of the word milliseconds in a table?

3.14 Milliseconds

or

3.14 milliseconds

Comment: This is a matter of style; adhere to the guidelines your editor sets forth. By the [official SI guidelines](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/section5-2.html), units should be treated as common nouns, and lowercased except when at the start of a sentence or in a title. See the previously asked *[Should Units of Measure be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173906)*

Comment: Generally it's not capitalized, but if you're publishing in a magazine or journal the editor has the final say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symbols of prefixes that mean a million or more are capitalized and those less than a million are lower case (M for mega (millions), m for milli (thousandths)).
Also, the names of all units start with a lower case letter except, of course, at the beginning of the sentence. There is one exception: in "degree Celsius" (symbol °C) the unit "degree" is lower case but the modifier "Celsius" is capitalized. Thus, body temperature is written as 37 degrees Celsius.

Comment: So the unit is *hertz* even though the abbreviation is *Hz*.

Comment: @GEdgar exactly right. [Hertz - simple.wiki](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hertz)

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly confident that the units are rarely capitalized when being placed after a value. Additionally, though, they are typically abbreviated when used in a scientific context.

So, I would recommend "ms" for "milliseconds" in your table, like [this article](http://www.nature.com/physics/looking-back/wolszczan/index.html) does. If you must spell it out, though, then I think the uncapitalized version would be preferred. However, ***always*** check the style guide for the journal you are submitting to, if you are planning on publishing this table in a journal.