# Units are proper or common nouns?

Tags: nouns, british-english, proper-nouns, measuring-units

Are units like newton, metre etc considered as proper or common noun?

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Try searching before posting; if you put your question into Google you'll immediately come to the Wikipedia article for the metric system which includes the phrase: "In languages where the distinction is made, unit names are common nouns (ie not proper nouns)." If you have additional questions beyond such basic research, feel free to share the research you've done and clarify your additional questions. Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Should Units of Measure be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173906)

Answer (score 1):

The names of the SI units are considered common nouns (i.e., they are not capitalized in English). (See §5.2 in http://physics.nist.gov/Pubs/SP330/sp330.pdf.)